# Entity Framework - Linq to Entities - Optional filter

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-6

I am struggling to figure out how to get a LINQ statement to produce a specific `WHERE` clause in SQL in a **single** statement.

I am after it producing something like this:

```
SELECT ColA, ColB, ColC, ColN...
FROM Orders
WHERE Client = @ClientId
AND (@CompanyId IS NULL OR @CompanyId = CompanyId)
```

My (**failing**) LINQ statement looks like this:

```
var includeAllCompanies = company == null;
var data = context.Orders.Where(o => o.Client.Id == clientId
           && (includeAllCompanies 
                 || (c.Company != null && c.Company.Id == company.Id)).ToList();
```

However, it always throws an exception when the variable `company` is NULL (**it works fine when it has been initialised**). The exception being:

> ```
> Non-static method requires a target.
> ```

My current fix is to split my LINQ statement into two. One using an `Expression<Func<>>` (to be transformed to a SQL statement with partial filtering). Then another that uses `Func<>` to perform the remaining filters on the returned list.

**`Expression<Func<>>` to let SQL do some of the work (excluding nullable objects)**

```
var data = context.Orders.Where(o => o.Client.Id == clientId).ToList();
```

**`Func<>` to then filter out the nullable objects**

```
data = data.Where(c => (territory == null 
       || (c.Territory != null && c.Territory.Id == territory.Id))).ToList();
```

This works, however, I want SQL to be performing this query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that, `company` is server-side variable. Regardles `includeAllCompanies` value, EF has to translate whole LINQ query to SQL - and in this case SQL doesn't know what is `company.Id` - so EF has to always get `company.Id` value in order to put into SQL query. Even if `company` is null (so that is why you get exception). I hope you see my point, if not - I'll try to give some sample.

In order get rid of exception you can do the following:

```
var companyId = company == null ? null  : (int?)company.Id;
var data = context.Orders.Where(o => o.Client.Id == clientId
           && (companyId  == null
                 || (c.Company != null && c.Company.Id == companyId)).ToList();
```